# How to make two dict into one dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make title and image dict data to one dict:

From this:

```
title = [{'title': 'Title Text One'},
         {'title': 'Title Text Two'},
         {'title': 'Title Text Three'}]
image = [{"image": "happy.jpg"},
         {"image": "smile.jpg"},
         {"image": "angry.jpg"}]
```

To this:

```
data = [{'title': 'Title Text One', 'image': 'happy.jpg'},
        {'title': 'Title Text Two', 'image': 'smile.jpg'},
        {'title': 'Title Text Three', 'image': 'angry.jpg'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, If your two array of dict have same length:

```
>>> title = [{"title":"Title Text One"},{"title":"Title Text Two"},{"title":"Title Text Three"}]
>>> image = [{"image": "happy.jpg"}, {"image": "smile.jpg"}, {"image": "angry.jpg"}]

>>> [{**title[i], **image[i]} for i in range(len(title))]
[{'image': 'happy.jpg', 'title': 'Title Text One'},
 {'image': 'smile.jpg', 'title': 'Title Text Two'},
 {'image': 'angry.jpg', 'title': 'Title Text Three'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
title = [{"title":"Title Text One"},{"title":"Title Text Two"},{"title":"Title Text Three"}]
image = [{"image": "happy.jpg"}, {"image": "smile.jpg"}, {"image": "angry.jpg"}]
data = image
[data[i].update(title[i]) for i in range(len(title))]
data
```

Output:

```
[{'image': 'happy.jpg', 'title': 'Title Text One'},
 {'image': 'smile.jpg', 'title': 'Title Text Two'},
 {'image': 'angry.jpg', 'title': 'Title Text Three'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.9+:

```py
out = [t | i for t, i in zip(title, image)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"title": "Title Text One", "image": "happy.jpg"},
    {"title": "Title Text Two", "image": "smile.jpg"},
    {"title": "Title Text Three", "image": "angry.jpg"},
]
```

---

Or:

```py
out = [{**t, **i} for t, i in zip(title, image)]
```